# Unable to pull in more than one row when parsing XML data into SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, parsing, sql-server-2012

I have seen a few XML parsing examples, and tried several but I am stuck on how to display all rows

My H:\Sample.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Level1>
    <Level2>
        <Level3>
            <Data>Line1</Data>
            <Data>Line2</Data>
            <Data>Line3</Data>
            <Data>Line4</Data>
        </Level3>
    </Level2>
</Level1>
```

My Levels don't have values attached, and I just want to produce a column of the 4 data lines.

I have tried three methods:

First Method: Using OpenRowSet and .nodes

```
   DECLARE @Data XML

    SET @Data = (   SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn
                    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\Sample.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as X )
    SELECT
        a.b.value('Data[1]','nvarchar(255)') as Detail
    FROM @Data.nodes('Level1/Level2/Level3')a(b)
```

Second Method:  Using Cross Apply

```
WITH xmlFile (Contents) AS (
    SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\Sample.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as XmlData
)
SELECT
    c.value('(Data)[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS Detail
FROM   XmlFile CROSS APPLY Contents.nodes ('(//Level1/Level2/Level3)') AS t(c);
```

Third Method:  Using sp_xml_preparedocument

```
DECLARE @hDoc AS INT
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @Data

SELECT Detail
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'Level1/Level2/Level3')
WITH (Detail [varchar](255) '@Data')

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

The first two examples show "Line1" and the last one shows NULL  (all just one line each)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @data xml;

set @data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
             <Level1>
                 <Level2>
                     <Level3>
                         <Data>Line1</Data>
                         <Data>Line2</Data>
                         <Data>Line3</Data>
                         <Data>Line4</Data>
                     </Level3>
                 </Level2>
             </Level1>';

select x.i.value('.', 'varchar(100)') as Detail
 from @data.nodes('//Level1/Level2/Level3/Data') as x(i);
```

Comment: I tried '' but didn't think to use '.' - makes sense - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You were almost there in your first attempt, just need to go a level deeper:

```
   DECLARE @Data XML

    SET @Data = (   SELECT CONVERT(XML, BulkColumn) AS BulkColumn
                    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'H:\Sample.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) as X )
    SELECT
        a.b.value('.','nvarchar(255)') as Detail
    FROM @Data.nodes('Level1/Level2/Level3/Data')a(b)
```

Comment: Looks like you both answered it about the same time.  Thanks!